# Any examples of using optaplanner to solve number of possible buildable combinations for a product given possible constraints?

Tags: linear-programming, optaplanner

Any examples of using optaplanner to solve number of possible buildable combinations for a product given possible constraints. So, say the product is made of a, b, c, d, e, and f parts. So examples of constraints are that if the product contains b, then it cannot contain f. In reality we could have a few thousand parts and a few thousand constraints.

Comment: A good implementation will probably exploit more information than you gave (with what's written it's a trivial SAT-like problem -> `b -> not f <-> not b or not f`). But even the task looks incomplete: are you interested in the *number* (model-counting) of valid combinations, the enumeration of all solutions (might be 10^100) or uniform-sampling of valid solutions. Without answering these questions, i would not decide on a tool early.

Comment: Sincerely appreciate your quick response here and I was expecting to be notified via email...maybe something I need to look at and turn on. Anyhow a quick answer is yes, yes and yes. Yes - need the number of valid combinations, yes need the valid combinations as well, for example - a&c&d&e&f or a&b&c&d&e. I will create a better and more complete example and post later tonite.

Comment: Enumerating all feasible solutions or estimating the number of feasible solutions is in most cases a very difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any examples like that, but it's a use case I've heard a few times before. There's Duncan's knapsack example that is pretty arguable close.
He has both a Quarkus and a Spring Boot implementation:

https://github.com/DuncanDoyle/knapsack-optaplanner-quarkus